# For document class amsart, the page numbers are too close to the last line

Tags: header-footer, positioning, amsart

How can I give the page numbers at the bottom a bit of space from the last sentence of each page?  In `amsart`, the page numbers almost touch the last sentence.

Comment: if you mean more than the first page, you are doing something that you are not telling us.  `amsart` places the page number in the running head on every page but the first.

Answer (score 3):

You can decrease the `\textheight` length and increase the `\footskip` length in the same proportion.  Doing so, the total height of the page will be unchanged.  For example:

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\addtolength{\textheight}{-\baselineskip}
\addtolength{\footskip}{\baselineskip}

\begin{document}

...

\end{document}
```

A useful package is `showframe`.  It allows you to see the page layout.

Comment: This will remove a line of text from the text block for the *entire* article.

Answer (score 2):

You can redefine the `firstpage` page style and insert a vertical strut that is high enough to push down the page number as far as you want:

[image]

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter
% Taken from the original definition in amsart.cls
\def\ps@firstpage{\ps@plain
  \def\@oddfoot{\normalfont\scriptsize \hfil\rule{0pt}{20pt}\thepage\hfil
     \global\topskip\normaltopskip}%
  \let\@evenfoot\@oddfoot
  \def\@oddhead{\@serieslogo\hss}%
  \let\@evenhead\@oddhead % in case an article starts on a left-hand page
}
\makeatother
\AtBeginDocument{\thispagestyle{firstpage}}% ...if you don't call \maketitle

\begin{document}

%\maketitle

\section{A section}

\sloppy\lipsum[1-10]

\end{document}
```

`\maketitle` issues `\thispagestyle{firstpage}`. However, if you're not using a title, you need to re-establish the page style at the start of the document (or somewhere on the first page). Hence the call to `\AtBeginDocument{\thispagestyle{firstpage}}`.